# What does this elif statement say?

Tags: python

I know this question may have been asked, but I can't find the actual answer to it. Thus here I have mine.

```
elif temp >= 10 :
    clothes = "dress"
elif temp >= 0 :
    clothes = "uniform"
```

temp > = 10 and temp >= 0, they overlap! Does it mean temp >= 0 is only going up till 10?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If temp is 11 you won't get to the second, presuming `clothes = "blah blah"` is not actually what is happening then they are different. If you ran the code with a few different numbers i.e over 10, 10 and under 10 it would be pretty clear

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I thought so too. I am a beginner. Everybody just voted down my question. Why so discouraging?

Comment: Its important to note the order of the elif conditions too. If they were reversed, the >= 10 code would never happen, and clothes would never be "dress". PS upvoting your question cause even though its very beginner, its a good question for a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the `elif` statements can be chosen.  If execution reaches the end of one `elif`, it will skip all the other `elif`s connected to the same `if`  .(That's why it's called "elif", for "else if".)

In your case the first will be chosen if `temp >= 10`, and if it is chosen the second `elif` will be skipped,  The second `elif` will be chosen if `temp >= 0` *and* the first was not chosen, which means it will be chosen if temp is between 0 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The first `elif` will be executed if `temp => 10` and the second `elif` will be executed if `10 > temp >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Elseif is the same as Else followed by if. In other words

```
if x > 10:
   "Some code"
else:
   if x > 5:
     "Some more code"
```

Is the same as

```
If x > 10:
  "Some code"
elif x>5:
   "Some more code"
```

The difference is that the latter one is easier to read.